# How to display data in Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a cigarette counter app in Ionic 4. When the user clicks the button 'Add One' in 'counter' segment, counter data is being pushed to storage. I need to retrieve the data from the storage and display it in a table in the 'history' segment. I am unable to display the data using the following piece of code:

```
this.service.getConsumptions().then((data: consumption[]) => {
            this.histories = data;
            console.log(data);
          })
```

home.page.html:

```
   <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="segment" color="dark">
          <ion-segment-button value="counter">
            Counter
          </ion-segment-button>
          <ion-segment-button value="history">
            History
          </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>

      <div *ngIf="segment == 'counter'">
        <h1 class="keski">Consumption today</h1>
        <p class="keski">{{ today.date }}</p>
        <p class="keski">{{ today.consumption }}</p>
        <p class="keski">{{ today.last_smoked }}</p>
        <ion-button expand="block" color="dark" (click)="addOne()">Add one</ion-button>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="segment == 'history'">
        <h1 class="keski">Recent consumption</h1>
        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col><b>Date</b></ion-col>
            <ion-col><b>Consumption</b></ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row *ngFor="let history of histories">
            <ion-col>{{ history.date }}</ion-col>
            <ion-col>{{ history.consumption }}</ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </div>

    </ion-content>
```

consumption.interface.ts:

```
export interface consumption {
    date: string,
    consumption: number,
    last_smoked: string
}
```

home.page.ts:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { consumption } from '../consumption.interface';
    import { KulutusService } from '../kulutus.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })

    export class HomePage {

      constructor(private service: KulutusService) { }

      segment: any = "counter";
      today = {} as consumption;
      histories: consumption[] = [];

      ngOnInit() {

        this.service.getConsumptions().then((data: consumption[]) => {
          if (data == null) {
            this.today.consumption = 0;
            this.today.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
            this.today.last_smoked = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
          } else {
            for (let consumption of data) {
              if (consumption.date == new Date().toLocaleDateString()) {
                this.today = consumption;
              }
            }
          }

          this.service.getConsumptions().then((data: consumption[]) => {
            this.histories = data;
            console.log(data);
          })
        })

      }

      addOne = () => {
        this.today.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        this.today.consumption += 1;
        this.today.last_smoked = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

        this.service.getConsumptions().then((data: consumption[]) => {
          let consumptions = data;
          // there is at least one consumption
          if (consumptions != null) {
            let current_exists = false;
            for (let consumption of consumptions) {
              // use current date
              if (consumption.date == this.today.date) {
                current_exists = true;
                consumption.date = this.today.date;
                consumption.consumption = this.today.consumption;
                consumption.last_smoked = this.today.last_smoked;

                // add current consumption to history
                for (let history of this.histories) {
                  if (history.date == this.today.date) {
                    history.date = this.today.date;
                    history.consumption = this.today.consumption;
                    history.last_smoked = this.today.last_smoked;
                  }
                }

              }
            }
            // new date
            if (current_exists == false) {
              consumptions.push(this.today);
              this.histories.push(this.today);
            }
            this.service.saveConsumption(consumptions);
          } else {
            // no consumptions at all
            this.service.addConsumption(this.today);
            this.histories = data;
          }
        })
      }

    }
```

consumption.service.ts:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
    import { consumption } from '../app/consumption.interface';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class KulutusService {

      constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

      getConsumptions = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.storage.get("consumption").then((consumptions) => {
            resolve(consumptions);
          })
        })
      }

      addConsumption = (newConsumption: consumption) => {
        this.storage.get("kulutus").then((data: consumption[]) => {
          let kulutukset = data;
          let loytyy_nykyinen = false;
          if (kulutukset == null) {
            kulutukset = [{date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(), 
              consumption: 0, last_smoked: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()},
            ]
          }
          for (let kulutus of kulutukset) {
            // use current date
            if (kulutus.date == newConsumption.date) {
              loytyy_nykyinen = true;
              kulutus.date = newConsumption.date;
              kulutus.consumption = newConsumption.consumption;
              kulutus.last_smoked = newConsumption.last_smoked;
            }
          }
          // new date
          if (loytyy_nykyinen == false) {
            kulutukset.push(newConsumption);
          }
          this.storage.set("kulutus", kulutukset);
        }
        )}

        saveConsumption = (kulutukset: consumption[]) => {
          this.storage.set("kulutus", kulutukset);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there any console error? Also, make your segment data type to string.

Comment: @jithil There is no console error.

Comment: Please check the below answer. I couldn’t see anywhere we are assigning “history” to the segment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified your code locally. Only the missing part is

```
this.segment = "history";
```

in `addOne()` function.

Rest is fine. Please see the proof below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, in the provided code, you are not setting `this.segment = “history”;` on `addOne` click function

Forgotten or are you making it somewhere else?

Please check.

Comment: This is not related to the problem.

Comment: So, how the segment will get value history here? Without the history value, the addon click will not work.

Comment: I tried to add `this.segment = "history"`, but nothing new happens. The data is still not being displayed in the history segment.

Comment: How you are binding your button click ?

Comment: It’s missing the click event binding. Add (click)=“addOne” in the history button

Comment: There is already a click event binding in the history as shown here: `<ion-button expand="block" color="dark" (click)="addOne()">Add one</ion-button>`

Comment: I'm copying the code localy in my machine. Will rectify this case soon.

Comment: I added the consumption.interface.ts

Comment: @aleksejjj, please see the proof of working sample after making the suggestions.